Enlarging Windows recovery partition on a non-OS disk
I'm trying to recover from an error on Windows update (security update KB5034441 failing), and I have read many posts suggesting enlarging the disk's recovery partition, so it has more than 250MB free space.
I have two disks on the computer, each having its own Windows installation. It's not a "dual boot" configuration (ie the Windows Boot Manager is not involved). They are two independent installations and I choose the installation to boot from the BIOS menu (pressing F12 during power-on, this displays the BIOS boot menu). I opted for this configuration so that a disk can be removed, cloned etc without affecting the other. Both disks are MBR, and the recovery partition is 530MB large for both.
So now I can use one disk, and I want to repair the other one. I guess not having to repair the disk with the (currently active) OS, should rather make things a little easier. I have considered quite a few solutions, but I don't know which would be the "best", and the safest particularly. For example:

Follow the Microsoft-recommended "manual" procedure (using diskpart), just for the other disk. Can it be done really? I'm also wondering if deleting and re-creating the recovery partition alone would be enough (I would like to avoid shrinking the OS partition, who knows what this could do to the files there), as the partition is 530MB (well above 250MB) and all its space will be free, no?
Deleting and re-creating the partition (or deleting all its contents), maybe enabling special priviledges, or using some other tool. I'm not given any such option (incl assiging a drive letter there) in Computer Management/Storage/Disk Management.
Using a third-party tool, like EaseUS. I have never tried such tools, and I'm a bit afraid actually. It has a "Crashed PC" facility, but what I can comprehend is that it will create a bootable USB drive, so you can boot the computer and copy the data files to another disk, finally having to perform a clean Windows installation.

So what should I do? I'm open to alternative suggestions from experts, particularly taking into account that I'm trying to fix a disk not containing the currently running OS.

The correct way to solve this problem, and the only way you should correct the problem, is to delete the WinRE then create a new partition that is larger and run a command to apply the WinRE to that partition. Shrinking the Windows system partition is perfectly safe. The answer to the duplicate if followed precisely is perfectly safe and will absolutely work.

@Ramhound, thank you for your comment. I had actually read the linked answer. Quite answers my question, however there is a difference, I want to perform the fix for an installation that is not the currently active one - I cannot boot from that installation. Is it OK to do from the other one?

I wouldn’t since those instructions are only meant to be ran within the running Windows install which means all you should do is make the other install bootable. Doesn’t change the fact the solution to install KB5034441 is described in that existing question. I can only speak to the that specific solution. Worth pointing out KB5034441 is really only applicable systems with Secure Boot. The entire reason the WinRE got larger is due to the vulnerability Microsoft patched which your not vulnerable since you have Legacy Boot enabled.
